# Почему nginx может не признавать алиас папки, в то время как если установить алиас файла, то все норм

Tags: nginx

Я хочу расположить в корне несколько файлов, но nginx отдает их только первым способом:

## такой вариант работает

```
location /robots.txt {
alias /********/root_dir/robots.txt;
}
```

## такой не работает

```
location / {
alias /********/root_dir;
}
```

конфиг:

```
upstream django {
         server unix:///*************************/**.sock;
    }

    server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /*******************************/**.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /*************************/****.key;
        server_name *******************;

        charset     utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;
        location /media  {
        alias /**********************/media; 
        }
        location /static {
        alias /*******************************/static_in_dev;
        }



        location /robots.txt {
        alias /****************************/root_dir/robots.txt;
        }

        location /favicon.ico {
        alias /***************************/root_dir/favicon.ico;
        }



        location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        proxy_connect_timeout       100;
        proxy_send_timeout          100;
        proxy_read_timeout          100;
        send_timeout                100;
        uwsgi_read_timeout          100;
        include     /*************************/uwsgi_params; 
        }
        access_log  /**************************/nginx.log;
        error_log  /****************************/nginx_err.log;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ***.***.***.***;
        return 301 https://**************.ru;
}
```

Comment: Потому что надо слеш дописать. Впрочем в данном случае правильнее использовать `root`

Comment: пробовал все комбинации (с рутом и разными слешами), не отдает. Может надо как то джанге сообщать об этой папке?

Comment: Может надо. Но для этого надо показать весь конфиг.

Comment: добавил конфиг.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь добавить второй location / ?